# Why MaterialRadioButton changing its color when I disable it?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm using `MaterialRadioButton` and when I disable it using `android:enabled="false"` the circle color become white but I want same color regardless if enabled it true or false

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialRadioButton" />
```

**Theme**

```
<style name="MaterialRadioButton">
    <item name="colorSecondary">#66BB6A</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "buttonTint" attribute in xml to fix some color for your radio button.